# MySQL : Updating Cells

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a mySQL statement.

I've got a mySQL table that looks like this:

```
Name Year Score   Address       Zip
Joe  2010   A     NULL          NULL
Joe  2009   B     123 Main St.  03755
Mary 2010   B     NULL          NULL
Mary 2009   C     234 Elm St.   03866
```

I need to grab the 2009 addresses and zips and put them in their respective 2010 cells. Unfortunately, I've got a lot of names.

The names are distinct-- Joe only refers to one Joe and Mary refers to only one Mary.

I know that it would be better to have a separate table with the addresses. But, I've simplified my example a bit. The table isn't designed perfectly, but the above is a problem that I need to solve.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the denormalized nature of this table (which you've recognized), you can use a self-join to accomplish this:

```
UPDATE mytable a
INNER JOIN mytable b 
    ON a.Name = b.Name 
    AND a.Year = 2010 
    AND b.Year = 2009
SET a.Address = b.Address, 
    a.Zip = b.Zip;
```

Comment: Dont you mean a.Address and b.Zip in the `SET`?

Comment: @Stephen, the "a" alias refers here to the 2010 records (which are the ones to be updated).  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Ben Your original statement said `SET Address = b.Address, Zip = b.Zip` - i.e. it referred to generic addresses and zips. My comment was misleading though, I typoed on the 'b.zip' - should have been 'a.zip'

Comment: Hi Ben,
Thank you for the message. I really appreciate it. I tried your suggestion, but I got: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tester2 a INNER JOIN tester2 b ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.Year =' at line 4

I named the table tester2. 

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!
-Laxmidi

Comment: Stephen/Laxmidi - Thanks for the comments.  I updated my answer accordingly.